# How to schedule a task at regular intervals without using threads in Java?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a Java program that requires me to schedule a task to take place at regular intervals. But the restriction is I cannot use threads.

I have come across Timer and TimerTask, but I'm not sure whether they create threads or not..

Is there a way to accomplish this without using threads?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every statement is executed by a thread. Either you use the main thread for running the scheduled tasks, or you create a separate thread to do it. (Technically speaking you're using threads either way.) You seem confused, Confused_Programmer. I suggest you clarify your question a bit.

Comment: @aioobe I guess my question is can i used Timer and TimerTask without violating the "don't use threads" restriction?

Comment: sounds like homework, and I assume you mean without using more than one Thread. The answer would be: while(true){ doTask(); Thread.sleep(timeoutInMilliseconds);}

Comment: @FlyingSwissman Thanks! But Im curious, why not Timer and TimerTask ?

Comment: because thats the simplest solution that meets your requirement

Comment: @Confused_Programmer You should explain this strange "no threads" requirement. If this is homework, say so, and quote the exact terms of the assignment.

Comment: @Confused_Programmer, you can't even implement a simple "Hello World" program without using threads. Please clarify.

Comment: @BasilBourque this is one part of the assignment which is for a process ( have a class) to read from a file and write to another file. The restriction given is to not use threads.

Comment: @aioobe Yes this is why Im confused at to why I'm given this restriction. Hence the question.

Comment: @FlyingSwissman I need the task to start at a particular time. Can that be done with thread.sleep() ?

Comment: I think we can safely assume the homework assignment instructed no *additional* threads.

Answer (score 2):

All Java timer, even the Swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), uses a separate thread to wait and trigger the event at the appropriate time.

If you program has to do something at regular intervals, but cannot start new threads, then your main thread has to do it.

But, can it? What is it doing otherwise?

If the main thread is otherwise idle, you can calculate the amount of time until next event, and [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) until then.

Comment: So, read the file, sleep, read, sleep, read, sleep, read, sleep, read, ... Zzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application design. A possible way is to design your application as a task to be executed. And launch it with Cron job (time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems).

Comment: @Andreas , totally agree.   But if you launch a java application it will have serval threads --> main , garbage collector etc. So I guess the intention is to avoid creation of additional worker threads

Answer (score 0):

You can try Quartz scheduler. Though it uses thread pool internally. It is stable and efficient.

Comment: Quartz is good, but not suitable for this question, since the thread pool violates the *"without using threads"* requirement.

Answer (score 0):

## `Thread.sleep`

As [the answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36874241/642706) says, you can sleep your current thread repeatedly to perform a recurring task. I understand your situation is a specify requirement in a homework class assignment to not use threads. I assume the intention of the assignment is to use no *additional* threads. Your executing code is always in a thread. Every Java app begins with an initial thread provided by the JVM.

But you should know that in real work that requirement of “no more threads” would be silly; the very purpose of threads is to carry out tasks on a different time frame. So, for real work I would recommend other more elegant, flexible, and powerful ways (search for Java [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), and [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)).

But for your homework, the [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class does offer a static method [`sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) for putting the current thread to sleep.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of up to nanoseconds. Part of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Back-ports available for Java 6 & 7 and for Android.

The [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum makes the conversion to milliseconds self-documenting.

Note that a sleeping thread may be awakened by another thread or by the JVM. When this happens, the awakened thread experiences an [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

```
long millisToSleep = java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis ( 5 );

Instant now = Instant.now ();
Instant limit = now.plus ( 1 , ChronoUnit.HOURS );

while ( Instant.now ().isBefore ( limit ) ) {
    System.out.println ( "Doing some stuff at " + Instant.now () );
    // … do some stuff.
    System.out.println ( "Going to sleep for " + millisToSleep + " milliseconds." );
    try {
        Thread.sleep ( millisToSleep );  // I do not recommend this approach, but it works. Better to use a 'ScheduledExecutorService'.
    } catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
        System.out.println ( "This thread’s sleep was rudely interrupted at " + Instant.now () + ". Stopping any further work." );
        break; // Bail out of the 'while' loop.
    }
}
```